# How to install .so file generated by cmake to use in python3

Tags: python, import, cmake, pybind11, .so

I have generated a X.so file using pybind11 and cmake to use my c++ function in python .
the function and file name both are pow .
i used python code blow and i does not work .
How can I install and import my .so file in python3 program ?

```
setup (name = 'pow',
   version = '0.1',
   author = "Nobody",
   description = """Install precompiled extension""",
   packages=[''],
   package_data={'pow': ['~/Desktop/pybinmod1/pow.so']},
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should create your setup.py using cmake `configure_file` and `file(GENERATE )`
   note: file is needed to use some generator expression (`$<...>`) while configure file is use to replace some CMake variable (`@...@`)

python/setup.py.in:

```py
setup(
  name='@PROJECT_NAME@',
  version='@PROJECT_VERSION@',
  author='...',
  author_email='...@...',
  url='https://github.com/...',
  distclass=BinaryDistribution,
  cmdclass={'install': InstallPlatlib},
  packages=find_packages(),
  package_data={
  'pow':['$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:pyPow>'],
  },
```

see: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11/blob/main/python/setup.py.in

```
configure_file(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/python/setup.py.in
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python/setup.py.in
  @ONLY)
file(GENERATE
  OUTPUT ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python/setup.py
  INPUT ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python/setup.py.in)
```

see: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11/blob/main/cmake/python.cmake

2. Add few `__init__.py`

```
set(PYTHON_PROJECT_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python/pow)
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${PYTHON_PROJECT_DIR}/__init__.py CONTENT "__version__ = \"${PROJECT_VERSION}\"\n")
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${PYTHON_PROJECT_DIR}/pow/__init__.py CONTENT "")
```

3. then build your wheel package

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT python/dist/timestamp
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory dist
  ...
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:pyPow>   ${PYTHON_PROJECT}/pow
  COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} setup.py bdist_wheel
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python/dist/timestamp
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY
    python/setup.py.in
  WORKING_DIRECTORY python)

# Main Target
add_custom_target(python_package ALL
  DEPENDS
    python/dist/timestamp
  WORKING_DIRECTORY python)
```

4. once you pip install your newly package (should be in `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python/dist`)
   You should be able to use:

```py
import pow.pow import ...
```

You can find a full Demo here:
ref: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11